# add and delete items in data set using python

Tags: python

I need a develop a taxi booking app.
One of the features is adding a new vehicle to the available vehicle list and if you want you can be able to remove it from the vehicle list.

I use a dictionary data structure to implement this problem,

[image]

This code will display the available vehicle list

```
vehicals = {"car":["3-4","AC/Non A/C"],"van":["6-8"],"3 Wheelers":["3","Not Avilable A/C"]}
number_of_items = len(vehicals)
i=1

print("Available Vehicals List")
for key, value in vehicals.items():
    print(str(i)+"."+key)
    i+=1
```

so I want to update this list after adding a new item to this dictionary or delete an item from this list.

Answer (score 2):

To add new data it is simple. You have

1. `vehicals['new_car'] = value`
2. For example you already have one following dict

`new_data = {'new_car': ["5-12"], 'new_car_2': ["4-6"]}'`,

you can simply update old dict by
`vehicals.update(new_data)`

to delete old ones you also have two ways:

1. simply `vehicals.pop('car_to_delete')`
2. `del vehicals['car_to_delete']`

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new item by simply:

```
vehicles['new_item'] = value
```

and delete an old one by:

```
vehicles.pop('old_item')
```